# ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build'"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, restify

I am developing a web app using reactjs and nodejs technologies and after that, I deployed it on HEROKU, but when I run on Heroku it gives me an error
**ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build'"**
and I observe one thing **stat '/app/client/build'** this path not change at anytime I dont know why because I am a new learner in reactjs and nodejs.

**server.js**

```
    var restify = require("restify");
    var server = restify.createServer();
    
    function respond(req, res, next) {
        res.send('Hello Restify!');
    }
    
    server.get('/hello', respond);
    server.get("/*", restify.plugins.serveStatic({
      directory: __dirname+"/client/build",
      default: 'index.html',
      appendRequestPath: false
     })
    );
    var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    server.listen(port, function() {
        console.log("Listening on " + port);
    });
```

Comment: Are the files there in the path ``/app/client/build``?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this might be erroring out is because the `/client/build` directory might not exist.

- Make sure when you do a `git add` you are including this folder (i.e maybe you have `.gitignore` file that is excluding this directory
- Once you push to heroku, you can verify all the files on the server by:

```
heroku run bash # should take you to the current dyno's bash
ls              # do you see your client directory?
cd client 
ls              # do you see your build directory?
```